# distribute gcc 4.7 program with shared libraries on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, dyld, gcc4.7

I've compiled a command-line tool against some C++ dynamic libraries using GCC 4.7 on Mac OS X 10.8. On the development system, the compiler was installed by MacPorts into `/opt/local` and the libraries reside in `/usr/local/lib`. The dynamic libraries are compiled from source alongside the program. (But they're built by `cmake` and I don't want to mess with that system.)

When I try to run it on another machine by putting the necessary dylibs into the executable's directory and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, it complains about an undefined symbol in the C++ standard library. It appears to be trying to load the older, builtin GNU standard library from `/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib`.

How can I force the system to load the desired `libstdc++`?

Comment: You mean `/opt/local/lib` don't you?  This is world of pain, if it's anything like CentOS!  Can I ask why you don't use Apple Clang 4 and libc++.dylib?

Comment: @trojanfoe GCC's libraries are in `/opt/local/lib`, the third-party library built from source installs into `/usr/local/lib`. Didn't use Clang because the application is portable to Linux; Macs are only used for development. (It installs onto Linux just fine, but I want to the binary with another developer, who only needs to use it, not build it.) Also, the `cmake` system is hardcoded to GNU AFAICT and the 3rd-party library isn't tested with Clang.

Comment: I think you are looking at the linker `rpath` stuff in order to tell the library where to look for dependencies. It's horrible and no way to start the new year...